# Relative path in JAX-RS

Tags: path, jersey, jax-rs, relative-path, include-path

I'm using Maven Jax-RS version 1.19

I am searching for a way to get to a path that is relative.

So for example:

My url: **localhost/css/all**

This url goes to a controller for the css

When i post the following url:
**localhost/parameter/anotherparam/css/all**

Then i also want to go to the same controller.

I couldn't really find an answer fit to my question in the suggestions or on google.
*(Funny that Stackoverflow can still search there own site better than google)*

So here is my question:

How do you make a relative path in Jax-RS so that the path that matches always follows no matter what the url is up front (or back)

my css controller:

```
@Path("/css")
@Singleton
public class CssController{

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public Response getCss(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("id") String id
       String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/css/"+id+".css");

        File f = new File(path);
        if (f.exists()) {
            return Response.ok(new Viewable(path)).build();
        } 
        return null;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included the following regex to my path to make it take a parameter or not so now the url

**css/all**

and

**/test/alsotest/css/all**

both go to the css controller:

```
@Singleton
@Path("{param1 : ^(?![\\s\\S])|(\\w+/)*?}css/{id}")
public class CssController {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response getCss(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("id") String id) 
    {
        String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/css/"+id+".css");

        File f = new File(path);
        if (f.exists()) {
            return Response.ok(new Viewable(path)).build();
        } 
    return null;
}
```

**Please steal nicely!**

with regex:

**^(?![\s\S])|(\w+/)*?**

in parameter:

**{param1 : ^(?![\s\S])|(\w+/)*?}**

so the full path for me is:

**{param1 : ^(?![\s\S])|(\w+/)*?}css/{id}**

I think this is also usefull for images and such, due to the relative path they can have, this way, location of calling doesn't matter, only the location of the resource!

I would like the thoughts of you stackoverflow people on this topic.

Looking forward!